# android - receive custom event on another thread

Tags: android, multithreading, event-handling, runnable

I'm using a background thread to do some work. Upon specific condition, I fire a custom event to notify all listeners.

My problem is I need the that event handler to be called in the main thread (which registers to the event) not the background thread (which fires the event).

Code explanation if useful:

**Background class**

```
public class Background implements Runnable {

    public Background() {
        Thread worker = new Thread(Background.this);
        worker.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // some work here
        boolean isDone = true;
        if (isDone) {
            fireEvent(new Object());
        }
    }

    public interface MyEventListener {
        public void onNewEvent(Object obj);
    }

    private final ArrayList<MyEventListener> listeners = new ArrayList<Background.MyEventListener>();

    public boolean registerEvent(MyEventListener listener) {
        return listeners.add(listener);
    }

    private void fireEvent(Object obj) {
        // fire event called in the background thread
        for (MyEventListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onNewEvent(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

**Foreground class**

```
public class Foreground implements MyEventListener {
        Background back = new Background();
        public Foreground() {
            back.registerEvent(Foreground.this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNewEvent(Object obj) {
            // I need this function to be called in the main thread which initiated this class
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Loopers and Handlers from Android SDK. Here's an example from dev docs:

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
      public Handler mHandler;

      public void run() {
          Looper.prepare();

          mHandler = new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                  // process incoming messages here
              }
          };

          Looper.loop();
      }
  }
```

In this example Handler instance is bound to the Thread, where it was created(LooperThread). Later you can get a Handler instance from another thread and send message to it. The message will be dispatached within handleMessage(), i.e. inside LooperThread.

So, in your other thread you can do something like this(pseudocode):

```
class MyOtherThread{
    public void run(){
       Handler handler = LooperThread.getHandler();
       handler.sendMessage(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! - but I'm beginner with threads, can you post a complete example that function the same as my code?

Comment: Mighter, in this question, class LooperThread is not appropriate, because the thread from which the action is started already exists - it is the main UI thread. How would you change your example, to initiate activity on the main UI thread (which already has a running looper.loop)?  https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html says "new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())", but I'm not sure how to use that here.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I think this depends on what you're trying to do. You maybe. If you just want to execute something in UI thread, you can simply wrap it with runOnUiThread(); Again, I can't suggest a solution without seeing your code.